# Calculate height of a projectile in rotating spaceship reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, projectile, coriolis-effect

In a rotating reference frame, or in a rotating spaceship, the apparent gravity felt by an object is the centrifugal force. Any moving object also experiences a Coriolis force. When I want to do calculations with a projectile (an object thrown across the circle in such a rotating frame), how do I take into account that the Coriolis acceleration constantly changes? I have been doing some calculations using the projectile equation and changing the *acceleration* variable to the Coriolis and centrifugal acceleration. But obviously, this is not correct. Lastly, how can I derive the maximum height of such projectile in this rotating frame of reference, given launch angle, angular velocity, and the radius of the circle?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The position vector $~\mathbf r~$ is

$$\mathbf r=\mathbf R+\mathbf R',$$

where

$$\mathbf R= \left[ \begin {array}{c} -\rho\,\sin \left( \theta \right) 
\\ -\rho\,\cos \left( \theta \right) 
\\ 0\end {array} \right] 
$$
$$\mathbf R'=\left[ \begin {array}{c} X\\ {\frac {\sin \left( 
\alpha \right) X}{\cos \left( \alpha \right) }}-\frac 12\,{\frac {g{X}^{2}}
{{v}^{2} \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
\\0\end {array} \right]
 $$

so that

$$\mathbf r=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\rho\,\sin \left( \theta \right) +X
\\ -\rho\,\cos \left( \theta \right) +X\tan \left( 
\alpha \right) -\frac 12\,{\frac {g{X}^{2}}{{v}^{2} \left( \cos \left( 
\alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}}}\\ 0\end {array}
 \right]
$$

you have one generalized coordinate which is $~X$ you can now obtain the equation of motion with :

$$T=\frac m2\mathbf{\dot{r}}\cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}} \\
U=-m\,g\,\mathbf r_y$$

and the external forces due the rotation

$$\mathbf F_s=\left[ \begin {array}{c} m \left( -{\omega}^{2}r_{{x}}-2\,\omega\,v_{
{y}} \right) \\ m \left( -{\omega}^{2}r_{{y}}+2\,
\omega\,v_{{x}} \right) \\ 0\end {array} \right]  
$$

with Euler- Lagrange you obtain differential equation

$$\ddot X(\tau)=f(X(\tau)~,\dot X(\tau)~,\omega~,v~,\alpha,\rho)$$

- $\alpha~$ launch angle
- $v~$ launch velocity
- $\omega~$ angular velocity
- $~\rho~$ circular radius

with the solution $~X(\tau~)$

**Numerical simulation**

I stop the simulation if  $~x'(\tau)\,\ge 2\,\rho\sin(\theta)~$

[image]

Comment: Hi there thank you for the great answer! is there any way that you can share your simulation with me? I have come across this article https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4588&view=html about the euler lagrange solution to that motion. What do you think of this?

Comment: @StevenOh I can give you just the simulation code containing the differential equations, not how you create those equations.

Comment: yes that would be super helpful! Can you send it to my email 22steveno@nagoyais.net ? Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SZfeNUlww4FzU14RTUWoCBRlCjXMp2R2/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: thank you so much :D

Comment: @StevenOh I looked again at your problem and find out that my solution wasn't quite  correct, the  vector R must be  independent of $~\Omega$ , see also the modification on google cloud. sorry for that

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thank you so much for putting effort in my question! This is really going to help with the physics paper I'm writing for my highschool degree!

Comment: I am really sorry but which final equations model the x and y positions of the object? I looked at the .mw file that you sent in maple soft and could not find/recgonize the final equations.

Comment: did you got the last version of my file?, please put your comment in my Maple file, so I know what is your problem

Comment: Yes i got the latest version! Sorry, your code is completely fine and the simulation works perfectly. I just wonder which line in your code actually represents the exact differential equations of the x and y coordinate of this motion.

Comment: you got second order differential equation for $~\ddot{X}(\tau)~$  ( (Maple ode) thus the numerical solution give you $~X(\tau)~$ the blue line is then the x,y components of $\vec R'$

Comment: Hi there thank you for your reply again! Your simulation was super useful! In addition, I found (sort of) a way to do it by transforming the rotation matrix. Because that the initial velocity in the inertial frame is the same as that in the non-inertial frame, I integrate the velocity and substitute it in the transformation. I made a python script simulating it and included a calculation in this google drive. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PhCdIr5zAIQGSK7LI_mQw-J-5ggaRKvt?usp=sharing   Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I don’t see the parabola equation, your equations are pure kinematic, but this problem is dynamic

Comment: The parabola equation would be the last line on the note document. I have also rewritten it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tbSih6uL7IMoruSAawxPvxJ9pTahMyUF/view?usp=sharing. <--- parabola equation in the rotating reference frame. Any advice would be appreciated thank you so much

Comment: Hi there, sorry so I compared the solution through Euler Lagrange(your solution) with that obtained through a rotation matrix. I am not sure why but the curves look a  lot different. And if I try it with larger launch angles they look even more different. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ofZ30VOigWAFbPY3ufbqOgq-wNnYvuSQ?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi can you write down the solution with rotation matrix

Comment: I obtained parametric equations: $$x(t)=vcos( \theta )tcos( \Omega t)-(vsin( \theta )t-R)sin( \Omega t)$$ and $$y(t)=vcos( \theta )tsin( \Omega t)+(vsin( \theta )t-R)cos( \Omega t)
$$ where v=launch velocity, omega=angular velocity of the spaceship, $\theta$ = launch angle with respect to the circular frame,

Comment: in the drive folder, I used v=28.5m/s, R=56m, $\Omega$=0.418

Comment: Where is g and $\alpha$ in your equations?

Comment: Hi so $\alpha$ would be $\theta$ and my apologies what does g represent in your equation?

Comment: g is the earth acceleration 9.81 $m/s^2$ and $\theta$ is not $\alpha$

Comment: Hi there, i apologize for my lack of knowledge but would you mind explaining why there is gravity in the equation?

Comment: You can find the equations here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79030/projectile-motion-formulas

Comment: Ohh! Sorry, my problem is actually set in outer space so there wouldn't be any gravity.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to calculate that is to use the non-rotating coordinate system.

Given is:
1 Launch velocity with respect to the rotating frame
2 Angle with respect to the circular perimeter of the rotating frame
3 Angular velocity of rotating frame with respect to non-rotating frame

The velocity with respect to the non-rotating frame is the vector sum of:
1 The velocity with respect to the rotating frame
2 The instantaneous velocity of the point of launch with respect to the non-rotating frame

The motion of the projectile with respect to the non-rotating frame is along a *straight line*. So you can, for example, calculate when that straightline motion will intersect the perimeter again.

By contrast, if you would insist on doing the calculation exclusively in the rotating frame then I think numerical analysis is the only way. The motion with respect to the rotating frame is not some nice function, such as a parabola, or (semi)circle, or hyperbola, etc. The simplest algorithm for plotting an arbitrary trajectory is [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).

Clearly, numerical analysis is an option only if you can set up a computer to do the calculation.